# What does su > echo "<username>" mean?

Tags: command-line, bash, sudo

When I was entering the command

```
su > echo  "sachin"
```

it was asking for a password. When I gave my password, some strange things happened as you can see:

[image]

One more thing: there is another user, *Hadoop*, on my laptop, but when I do

```
su > echo "Hadoop"
```

it says

> no passwd entry for Hadoop

What does this mean?

Comment: the su is the ask for super user permissions, the echo is to print something, echo <text> is to print text, the > is what follows, like, su > echo "sachin" is the same as su sachin, because echo "sachin" returns sachin

Comment: @Yousef's: No. `echo` is not executed. it is after the redirection command ">", so it is read as a file name. The rest of argument are passed to `su` as usual!

Comment: @Yousef's You might be thinking of `su $(echo "sachin")`. That would do what you're saying.

Comment: hmmmm, so sorry for the wrong info, i was not really sure about it but i tried it and that's what i first figured out, thanks for informing me with the right info

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Ah! Nice puzzle!

Just say "`exit`", and all your files will be there (and the output you miss in a file called `echo`).

Explication:

```
 su > echo user
```

is the same as

```
 su user > echo
```

So you are starting a (sub)shell with `su` (switch user) to your user, *with all output redirected to a file called `echo`*!

Look:

```
[romano:~] % cd tmp/dvd-usa-hd 
[romano:~/tmp/dvd-usa-hd] % ls
dvd-usa-hd_01_01.avi
[romano:~/tmp/dvd-usa-hd] % su > echo romano
Password: 
[romano:~/tmp/dvd-usa-hd] % ls
[romano:~/tmp/dvd-usa-hd] % exit
[romano:~/tmp/dvd-usa-hd] % ls
dvd-usa-hd_01_01.avi  echo
[romano:~/tmp/dvd-usa-hd] % cat echo
dvd-usa-hd_01_01.avi
echo
[romano:~/tmp/dvd-usa-hd] %
```

Comment: Good answer. The key confusing and interesting aspect of this puzzle is that, though we usually supply them at the end (or sometimes the beginning) of a simple command, redirections can actually go anywhere--even between arguments. We see commands like `su user > echo` all the time, and `> echo su user` with some frequency, but `su > echo user` almost never, as there's rarely any practical reason to write a command in such a confusing way. (That such syntax is accepted is occasionally useful when automatically generating commands from a program or script, though.)

Comment: @EliahKagan yes --- and the confusion here is enhanced by the file name. `su > stdout.txt user` wouldn't be so tricky...

Comment: @EliahKagan Learned!